# Add tags in chef firstboot

Tags: chef-infra

I am installing chef agent on my nodes using a bash script. I can add the recipe to firstboot.json but not able to add tags.  Is there any way to add tags to firstboot.json.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, tags are just a very slight bit of sugar for a `normal` level attribute called `tags` (or `node["tags"]` as you would write in a recipe). You can put something like `"tags: ["foo"]` in your bootstrap JSON.

Comment: Tried the same but didn't work, this is my firstboot.json  : 
{
 "normal": {
    "tags": ["mId=201"]
  },
"run_list" :[
   "recipe[apt::default]",
   "recipe[ntp::default]"
   ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered there is a native way to do this.

`--tags` takes a comma-separated list of tags to apply during the bootstrap.

```
> knife bootstrap <all the other options> --tags 'foo'

> knife node show <the node> -a tags
<the node>:
  tags: foo
```

I am astounded that this super-useful ability isn't documented anywhere, at least, I've never seen it, and I've been up and down the chef docs a lot.

I was googling just now and I found it by looking at [this commit](https://github.com/chef/chef/commit/b86ba5b0858676da98e0456d340ac2f1a031a0d1) in [this PR](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/3190). Thank you @thommay!

UPDATE: I admit that `knife bootstrap -h` shows `--tags TAGS Comma separated list of tags to apply to the node.` But I feel like i've never seen that before. Anyone know if it's new? That PR is from 2015.